# Heron local deployment getting error "Stop writing due to not yet connected to Stream Manage"

Tags: java, local, centos7

I am working on Heron on Centos7 while deploying the topology we are getting following error after install libunwind dependency also getting same error.

> [2017-05-30 09:24:31 +0000] [SEVERE]
>   com.twitter.heron.common.network.HeronClient: Failed to FinishConnect
>   to endpoint: /127.0.0.1:36597 java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused [2017-05-30 09:24:31 +0000] [INFO]
>   com.twitter.heron.network.StreamManagerClient: Stop writing due to not
>   yet connected to Stream Manager. [2017-05-30 09:24:31 +0000] [WARNING]
>   com.twitter.heron.network.MetricsManagerClient: Cannot connect to the
>   metrics port with status: CONNECT_ERROR, Will Retry..

Answer (score 0):

This dependency has been eliminated now. libunwind is statically linked in the newer versions. Give it a try and let us know. Further documentation is available at https://apache.github.io/incubator-heron/